# Woocommerce singe product custom gallery output works just on the first slide

Tags: plugins, functions, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I copied the "product-image.php" to my theme folder in order to change the HTML output a bit, so instead of using `wc_get_gallery_image_html` I created my function and changed the output there.

Here's the original [function](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_gallery_image_html/)

and here's the modified one:

```
function my_custom_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id, $main_image = false ) {
$flexslider        = (bool) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_flexslider_enabled', get_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' ) );
$gallery_thumbnail = wc_get_image_size( 'gallery_thumbnail' );
$thumbnail_size    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', array( $gallery_thumbnail['width'], $gallery_thumbnail['height'] ) );
$image_size        = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_image_size', $flexslider || $main_image ? 'woocommerce_single' : $thumbnail_size );
$full_size         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_gallery_full_size', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_large_size', 'full' ) );
$thumbnail_src     = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $thumbnail_size );
$full_src          = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $full_size );
$image             = wp_get_attachment_image(
    $attachment_id,
    $image_size,
    false,
    apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_gallery_image_html_attachment_image_params',
            array(
                'title'                   => get_post_field( 'post_title', $attachment_id ),
                'data-caption'            => get_post_field( 'post_excerpt', $attachment_id ),
                'data-src'                => $full_src[0],
                'data-large_image'        => $full_src[0],
                'data-large_image_width'  => $full_src[1],
                'data-large_image_height' => $full_src[2],
                'class'                   => $main_image ? 'wp-post-image' : '',
            ),
        $attachment_id,
        $image_size,
        $main_image
    )
);

return '<div style="background-image:url(' . esc_url( $full_src[0] ) . ');" data-thumb="' . esc_url( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $full_src[0] ) . '"></a></div>';
}
```

I'm trying to use background images instead of images inside the slider, but it loads style only on the first slide.

btw I added this part `style="background-image:url(' . esc_url( $full_src[0] ) . ');"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in order to make it work there's a second file (product-thumbnails.php) using the same function, so if the default function is changed in one file, the second one must be updated too.